# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\sqrt{i}}}{n^2}=0 \; ?$

Tags: limits, power-series

I was wondering whether this limit converges to zero:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\sqrt{i}}}{n^2}=0
$$
And i'm pretty sure it is.

First, by intuition. I know that $\sum_{i=0}^n{i} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ~ $O(n^2)$, so i guess that $\sum_{i=0}^n{\sqrt{i}}$ is "less powerful", but i don't really know how much "lesser"

So, the thing that **really** interest me was: what is the "cardinality" of $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\sqrt{i}} \;? \quad$ Is it "equal ~" to $O(n)$? (I'm not sure i translated the words correctly. Does 'cardinality' is the right word for my description? I'm not familiar with these words in english, sorry. hope you understood what i meant).

Here is my thought:

$
{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\sqrt{i}}} = 
{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+...+\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}} =
{\sqrt{n} \big( \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{n}} +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} +...+ \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}} \big)} =
{{\sqrt{n} \big( \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} +...+ \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} \big)}}
$

and so:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\sqrt{i}}}{n^2} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{\sqrt{n} \big( \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}} +...+ \sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} \big)}}{n^2} \overbrace{<}^{(*)}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{\sqrt{n} \big( \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} +...+ \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} \big)}}{n^2} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{{\sqrt{n} \big( \overbrace{1 + 1 +...+ 1 + 1}^{n \, times} \big)}}{n^2} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sqrt{n} *n }{n^2} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \sqrt{n} }{n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{n} } = 0
$$

But my enlargement in $(*)$ above was too big.

I was wondering if you can suggest me some better way :)

Comment: Taking $\sum\sqrt i$ as approximately $\int\sqrt x dx$ you get roughly $\frac 23i^{\frac 32}$...

Comment: @abiessu 
oh nice! I didn't thought about integrals.. i wasn't sure whether this tool is comparable when dealing with natural numbers and sums.

so, according to your explanation, can we conclude that $\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt i$ ~ $O(n^{1.5})$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe
hmm.. not really.. That's bigger than my expression, doesn't it?
It's like $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt n  *\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\sqrt i}}{n^2}$

Comment: What do you mean when you say that your enlargement is too big? Your solution looks valid to me.

Comment: Cardinal is not the right word. Cardinals are not real numbers, and while they do have a notion of infinite summation, it has a much more robust definition, insofar as that every sum "converges", since it simply describes the cardinality of some set. You might want to talk about growth rate, but that is not the same as cardinality.

Comment: @rylen The link gives you that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt n   \sum_{i=0}^{n}{\sqrt i}}{n^2} = \frac{2}{3}$, which directly implies that $$ \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\sqrt i}}{n^2} \sim \frac{2}{3\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't say "this limit converges to zero". We either say,
"the limit of a sequence *is* zero", or "a sequence converges to zero".

"[Cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality)" is a concept for sets; it does not make sense to say the "cardinality of a series". You may be looking for the phrase "[growth rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)" for a sequence.

Now back to your question. The sequence in the question can be written as
$$
b_n=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}\quad \textrm{where   }
a_n=\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n}}\right)\frac1n\;
$$

But $a_n$ can be taken as a Riemann sum and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\int_0^1\sqrt{x}dx
$$

It follows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0\quad 
$$

---

As Matt E. pointed out in the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357633/lim-n-to-infty-frac-sum-i-0n-sqrtin2-0/4357646#comment9098379_4357633), your attempt actually solves the problem! Notice that
$$
|a_n|\le (\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n\textrm{  terms}})\cdot \frac{1}{n}=1
$$
shows that $a_n$ is a bounded sequence. On the other hand you have $\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$. Together you have $\lim b_n=0$.

Comment: very helpful! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can make very good approximations using generalized harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt i=H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ For large values of $n$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt i=\frac{2 n^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}+\zeta
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$
$$\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i=0}^n \sqrt i=\frac{2 }{3\sqrt n}+\frac{1 }{2n\sqrt n}+\cdots$$

Use it for $n=100$; the trucated series gives $\frac{403}{6000}=0.0671667$ while the exact value is $0.0671463$ (relative error of $0.03$%)

Comment: nice one! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Integrals can be a very useful tool to get equivalent of sequences. Notice that we have for each integer $k \geq 2$ :

$$\int_{k}^{k+1} \sqrt{t} \,dt \geq {\sqrt{k}} \geq \int_{k-1}^{k}  \sqrt{t} \,dt$$
since the square root function is an increasing function.

If we sum these inequalities, we get :

$$
\int_{1}^{n+1} \sqrt{t} \,dt \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k} \geq 1+\int_{1}^{n}  \sqrt{t} \,dt
$$

Then by integrating :
$$
\frac{1}{1.5}(n+1)^{1.5}-\frac{1}{1.5} \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k} \geq \frac{1}{1.5} n^{1.5}-\frac{1}{1.5}+1
$$
Therefore, we can deduce (the thing that interests you)
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k} \sim_{+\infty} \frac{n^{1.5}}{1.5}
$$

So we get the same result as you  :

$$
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \sqrt{i}}{n^{2}} = \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n^{1.5}}{1.5n^{2}} = \lim \frac{1}{1.5\sqrt{n}}  = 0
$$

If you are interested, using the same method we can obtain something more general
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^{\alpha}} \sim_{+\infty} \frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}$$

for any $\alpha<1$ and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \sim_{+\infty} \ln n$$
for the special case $\alpha=1$.

Comment: oh nice ! thank you!